Npgsql Error "PostgresException: 42P01 Did not find relation", until I refresh the page
I have a certain setup on postgresql that works just fine using the psql shell.
However, when I try to connect thoughout my Web App, I encounter a small bug.
Hey, I have a simple Postgresql 14 database setup that I will describe below :
A Database b contains two schemas : public and aph.
The public schema doesn't contain any relation, but the aph schema contains a test table named hey, with a single column acting as a primary key (defined as id int not null primary key).
All of these objects are owned by the postgres user.
A user named aph_auth, which can't login, is allowed to connect to the database cited above.
A user name aph_test inherits from aph_auth, which makes him able to connect to the database.
The aph_test user has a usage right on the schema and a select right on the table.
The setup looks something like this :
CREATE DATABASE b OWNER postgres;
--connect to the database

CREATE SCHEMA aph OWNER postgres;
CREATE TABLE aph.hey(id int not null primary key);

CREATE USER aph_auth NOLOGIN;
CREATE USER aph_test INHERIT IN ROLE aph_auth;

ALTER USER aph_test SET search_path TO aph;

REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE b FROM public;
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA aph FROM public;
REVOKE ALL ON TABLE aph.hey FROM public;

GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE b TO aph_auth;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA aph TO aph_test;
GRANT SELECT ON TABME aph.hey TO aph_test;

Note that using the shell, there are no password / right issues with my setup, everything works perefectly.
Using this setup, I want to conenct to the database and retreive the number of rows in my table using Blazor Web App (.net 8).
Here is what I did : 
Program.cs :
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AphContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration["Database:Aph"]));

AphContext.cs :
public AphContext(DbContextOptions<AphContext> options) : base(options)
{

}

public DbSet<Hey> Heys { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Hey>().ToTable("hey");
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

Hey.cs :
public class Hey
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

What my secrets.json file looks like :
{
  "Database": {
    "Aph": "Host=host; Database=b; Username=aph_test; Password=password; searchpath=aph;"
  }
}

Finally, I execute a count in my razor page :
@inject AphContext _aphContext
<p>@_aphContext.Projects.Count()</p>

This unfortunately doesn't work when I launch the app, but it does as soon as I refresh the page.
I tried to replace the aph_test logins by postgres logins in my connection string, and it work at app launch this time.
I can't figure out why I have to refresh the page in order for it to work with this setup. Can anyone help ?
PS : I only have to refresh once after startup, no matter how many times i navigate back and forth to my page.
Edit : Google Gemini suggested that I perform a "Pre-warm connection", which is basically running a useless SQL command at the very start of the application, which works. I'll still leave this issue for proper ways to fix it.
